# What was the humanist conception of subject/object?

Tags: ontology, psychology

In the introduction to Aldo Rossi's Architecture of the city, Peter Eisenman writes:

'Whereas the humanist conception attempted an integration of subject and object, the modernist conception polemically attempted their separation. The problematic nature of the practice of modern architecture with respect to the theory of modernism has to do precisely with its inability to effect this separation and thus its contamination with imperatives from the humanist conception' (p.5)

Could anyone help clarify this subject/object conception for me?

Sincerely,
A